# showing ClassCastException when i am loading Listview on Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In my project I have inserted "Two" Fragments on my MainActivity:

[image]

And on "leftside" fragment I want to load Listview and "Rightside" fragment I want to load just one empty view.

For this, I have tried the code below, but I it's showing an exception:

> ClassCaste Exception

What did I do wrong here?

---

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <fragment
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.ram_ramadevi.fragmentexample4.MenuFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        />

    <fragment
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.ram_ramadevi.fragmentexample4.RightSideFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.ram_ramadevi.fragmentexample4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**MenuList.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MenuFragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuFragment extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaapter;
    String[] android_Versions = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.MenuList);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        adaapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android_Versions);
        list.setAdapter(adaapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RightsideFragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffff"
>

</LinearLayout>
```

**RightSideFragment:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class RightSideFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.RightsideFragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the ClassCastException occurring? Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: in my MainActivity class near setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); i think this exception is coming

Answer (score 0):

In menu fragment change Fragment instead of Activity

```
 public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{
 //your logic
}
```

Comment: how can we extends Fragment in that class it's showing all errors

Comment: use onCreateView in menuFragment

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:context="com.example.newfragment.MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.example.newfragment.MenuFragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.example.newfragment.RightSideFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity:-**

```
package com.example.newfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

**menulist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MenuFragment:-**

```
package com.example.newfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;</n>
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaapter;
String[] android_Versions = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",      "10" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menulist, container, false);

    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    adaapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android_Versions);
    list.setAdapter(adaapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

**rightsidefragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00ffff">

</LinearLayout>
```

**RightSideFragment:-**

```
package com.example.newfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class RightSideFragment extends Fragment{

View rightView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rightView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rightsidefragment, container, false);
    return rightView;
}
}
```

Comment: you extended MenuFragment from Activity. it should extended from Fragment.

Comment: oh that's only mistack?and remaining everything fine?

Comment: and in MenuFragment plz use onCreateView() method, not onCreate. and make sure you have android-support-v4 liberry.

Comment: offcourse i have used this onCreateView in Menufragment class

Comment: @NikunjDobariya, Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.